# running Protractor test with directConnect:true through some warning

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am running protractor end-to-end tests without starting selenium server. Meaning 
By `directConnect:true`
My tests are running fine. But I am getting some warnings on console after protractor test start running as

```
Running "protractor:start" (protractor) task
[16:20:53] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:20:53] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Jasmine started
[1892:5332:1023/162132.079:ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_plugin from binding interface: memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator exposed by: content_browser
```

What is this error suppose to mean? And
how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're testing a "Chromium Application" (not sure, if that's the correct wording).

As far as I can tell, this seems a problem somewhere in `application vs. chromium vs. browser` and barely a Protractor issue.

If you want to dig deeper, here some links:

[Chromium README with reference to Mojom IDL and Bindings Generator](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/mojo/README.md#mojom-idl-and-bindings-generator)

[Documentation Mojom IDL and Bindings Generator](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/mojo/public/tools/bindings)

[Developer Question-Answer related to your error](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/services-dev/FRMxW4njLl8/A9M0oiSsAAAJ)